# Hbase Table not deleted from Phoenix

Tags: hbase, database-table, apache-phoenix

I have created table in hbase via phoenix. 
Why hbase table is not droped after deleted it from Phoenix and vise versa.?

Why deleting a table from Phoenix takes considerably more time than deleting it from Hbase directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed, see https://github.com/forcedotcom/phoenix/issues/536, so when you drop the table using Phoenix, it will also get deleted from HBase.  However when you bypass Phoenix and directly drop the table from HBase, the Phoenix metadata will be in a bad state, so avoid doing that.  Typically if a table has been created using Phoenix, it should be dropped using Phoenix.